# How to arrange editor code in a game engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine, system-design

Our lightweight game engine need to keep its binary size small.

However, we must add some editor code to existing engine code. For example:

```
class Material {
    public:
    #some engine code
    bool InitWithMaterialSourceCode();

    public:
    # some code only used in editor mode
    void SetMaterialCachePath();
    std::string material_source_file_path;
    std::string GetMaterialSourceCode();
}
```

Some interface and variable are only used in editor mode. How should I arrange these code?

Here are my thoughts:

1, inheritance. Use an child class in editor mode, where all code lines in eninge using the parent class need to be modified.

2, duplication. Write another class for editor mode, which seems violate the rule of software engineering.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "editor code"? Does your engine have an editor that requires your classes to provide extra functionality / properties? Do those properties have any effect on the regular engine code? The decision depends a lot on your current design, I think.

Comment: There is too little information given to give good advice, but for me this raises concern if you try to solve the right problem. Maybe you can decompose your Material into smaller classes. One for Rendering only and maybe a factory class with a policy for caching.

Comment: @OutOfBound There are cases code should be placed in the Material class, for example `GetMaterialSourceCode`, as only running in editor mode need this interface keeped.

Comment: @heLomaN can you provide a minimal example of such a function and how it is used in the editor and engine (just class stubs and pseudo code functions). It really is impossible to give good advice without more knowledge on your design.

Answer (score 1):

it's done with `#define` / `#ifdef`

Comment: No it's not. Defining a class differently depending on macros is a sure way to violate ODR and a recipe for insane debugger behaviour while you track down the resulting random crashes.

Comment: @Quentin if you compile one program with one definition, and another program with another definition, and don't make them mix, you don't violate ODR

Comment: @AlexGuteniev absolutely. But experience has taught me that this "if" isn't nearly as robust as it seems, especially when you start messing around with dynamic libraries.